# Intranet opensource in Django?

Tags: django, intranet

I'm looking for some open source, free to change and use Intranet written on Python+Django.
Just want to find some foundation to build site on top of it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly are you asking for? Do you want to know what servers will be required? Or are you looking for some kind of hosting? You mention Intranet, so I assume you want to build a Django site, but don't know where to start?

Comment: Feature requirements needed! Is it just a set of information pages? In which case just use a CMS (try Django LFC if djang-cms isn't doing it for you). Or do you need messaging, email, shared to-do lists and other features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a prebuilt site, have a look at [Django-CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/en/tour-demo/), a Content Management System. If what you need is very simple, and you have a large amount of trust in your Users, you can probably get away using the `admin` contrib package that comes with Django.

For deployment, you're looking at setting up an Apache web server on an internal server somewhere, installing mod_wsgi, and deploying that way. There are many tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please what are features that are needed on your intranet. As Josh suggested, the Django-CMS will do good in most of the cases.